# jqgrid randId() produces duplicates after page reload

Tags: jqgrid

On my grid, after a user enters text on the bottom row, I am adding another row so they can fill out another row if needed.  The grid will grow as needed by the user.  This is working fine, however after a page reload and populating from db, the addrowdata() function does not honor existing row ids and creates duplicates, starting from 1 again, e.g. jqg1.  It should look at existing row ids and create new unique ids.  So if I have 5 rows already, it might start at jqg6.  Here is the relevant code inside onCellSelect:

---

```
var records = jQuery("#table-1").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
var lastRowId = jQuery("#table-1").jqGrid('getDataIDs')[records - 1];

if (lastRowId == id)
{  
    jQuery('#table-1').addRowData(undefined, {}, 'last');
}
```

---

I have also tried $.jgrid.randId() instead of undefined, same results as expected.

Thanks

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the error is in the part where you fill grid with the data from the database. The data saved in the database has unique ids. The ids are *not* in the form jqg1, jqg2, ... So if should be no conflicts. You should just fill the `id` fields of the JSON with the ids from the database.

One more possibility is that you just specify the `rowid` parameter (the first parameter) of `addRowData` yourself. In the case you will have full control on the new ids of the rows added in the grid.

The code of `$.jgrid.randId` function is very easy. There are `$.jgrid.uidPref` initialized as `'jqg'` and `$.jgrid.guid` initialized to 1. The `$.jgrid.randId` function do the following

```js
$.jgrid.randId = function (prefix)  {
    return (prefix? prefix: $.jgrid.uidPref) + ($.jgrid.guid++);
}
```

If it is *really required* you can increase (but **not** decrease) the `$.jgrid.guid` value without any negative side effects.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, I was hoping you would answer.  I am in fact saving the jqg1 values to the database, and repopulating the grid with these ids when the grid is filled upon page reload. I would like grid to create the unique ids which I will save in the database.  This way I won't have to go to the db, find the larest, increment, every time someone adds a row client side.

Comment: @krazy: I don't find it good. All databases which I know contain some kind of AutoIncrement integer type. For example in SQL you can declare the column with `int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL` or `int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) for more examples. The way in much more safe as the usage of ids generated in JavaScript. Which database you use?

Comment: The issue was about creating a unique row id, I now understand $.jgrid.randId does not look at existing values. The table has a composite primary key.  I will create my own rowId, thanks.

Comment: @krazy: You are welcome! In case of usage of composite key I use typically `key1 + '_' + key2 + '_' + key3` as the grid id because I have no underscore `'_'` inside of keys. Such simple transformation allows encode an decode the composite key in very simple way.